# Lotusscript to Java Conversion

Tags: java, spring, lotus-notes, lotusscript

Is there any easy way to convert code written in Lotusscript to Java?

I have an application written in Lotusscript for Lotus Notes that my clients wants converted to a web application.  Rather than move to XPages (or make the Notes db web-enabled), my clients prefers that I create a Java web application instead (Spring or another web framework, for example).

Any ideas or thoughts on this topic much appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Not if you're not working with Lotus, which is an entire ecosystem. You'll need to duplicate all Lotus functionality, plus the app- specific stuff.

Comment: Simon - yes, the Notes application to be converted currently resides on a Domino server.

Comment: Converting a Notes database to a Java web application is not going to be simple unless it's an incredibly simple Notes database. If it uses Lotusscript, it's already beyond the "incredibly simple" phase. You are far better off keeping the back end in Notes and producing a front end in a web-friendly way. The easiest web-friendly way for a Notes dev is just web-enabling. Doing it in XPages would be more capable and a better career-building experience for you, though painful. Building a front end entirely outside of Notes would require even more new knowledge without the safety of being inside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be a monumental task, since:

1. The actual Java language and LotusScript language (ignoring built-in functions and classes) are radically different.  One does not map cleanly to the other
2. Depending on what you want to do, you may not have all the Domino Classes you need in Java. The Notes UI classes are only implemented in LotusScript, not Java.
3. One saving grace is that all the *back-end* classes are mirrored between LotusScript and Java.
4. Another issue is that object management is handled much more cleanly in LotusScript than Java.  In Java, you have to be careful to recycle your objects manually, and in the correct order, otherwise you may get strangled by the Java garbage collector.

That's all I can think of offhand.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Eric.  I was afraid of it being such a huge task, but it looks like other people agree with your synopsis of the effort involved, so I'll run with that.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If your client prefers to eliminate the need of the Domino server/license, and insists on java, then manually converting the code [or its functionality] to java is your only option.

However, if the Domino server will remain, you can strategically combine the use of the LS2J classes and the methods available in the java.lang.class (class) to call the Domino/LotusScript functions [AND AGENTS] plus instantiate Domino/LotusScript objects from java.  This is the preferred method vs. re-writing the LotusScript code/agents.

Another approach is to use the Web Service Provider/Consumer services or convert/create the existing Notes Db to a Composite Application [with Domino Designer version 8+].  This allows you to "export" the .jar files/code and use them external to Domino.